# Accessing fb user using Parse' Cloud Code hosting

Tags: parse-platform

We are hosting a web app on Parse's Cloud Code Hosting service but I'm having a problem getting the logged in facebook user in Express code. I can see that the client side it working when I call Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn and I can get the user in main.js using request.user when the account is logged in from an iOS app, but the same doesn't work in app.js. I've tried following the cookie handling code in this guide https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/parseExpressCookieSession.html but I still get undefined when I try and access it.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I'm not sure where the process is failing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a reasonably common problem;

https://parse.com/questions/parseexpresscookiesession-cookie-session
https://www.parse.com/questions/parseusercurrent-on-express-is-undefined-when-loggin-with-facebook

Then I finally came across this;

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-facebook-user-session